# Can not compile to a native executable with Clozure CL on OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: build, common-lisp, ccl

I have created a simple hello world (hello.lisp) ,code:

```
(defun main ()
    (format t "Hello,World"))
```

, program to test CCL's native executable compilation. I proceed to compile and load buffer from the CCL GUI (using version Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.10-store-r16266  (DarwinX8664)).

When i test it:

```
    ? (main)
    Hello,World
    NIL
    ?
```

It finds the main function. When i proceed to compile it with:  `(save-application "/tmp/h" :toplevel-function #'main :prepend-kernel t)`, it proceeds with the operation and CCL exits.

The file is created and is arround ~56MB. When i try to run it though I get the following output:

> Error: There is no applicable method for the generic function:
>            #
>          when called with arguments:
>            (# :NOTE-CURRENT-PACKAGE #)
>   While executing: #, in process toplevel(6).
>   Error: There is no applicable method for the generic function:
>            #
>          when called with arguments:
>            (# :BREAK-OPTIONS-STRING T)
>   While executing: #, in process toplevel(6).
>   Error: There is no applicable method for the generic function:
>            #
>          when called with arguments:
>            (# :BREAK-OPTIONS-STRING T)
>   While executing: #, in process toplevel(6).
>   Error: There is no applicable method for the generic function:
>            #
>          when called with arguments:

And the errors proceed. What do I do wrong? Is it a bug?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the keywords `:note-current-package` and `:break-options-string` in the cocoa-ide of the sources.  Since `prepend-kernel t` prepends the kernel that was used in the current session, it seems that you would include the cocoa-ide startup in your application.  However, the methods dispatching on those keywords only dispatch on ´ns-application`s, which your new application seems not to be.

The solution might be to prepend a kernel without cocoa-ide, either by loading your code into a non-GUI image, or by using the pathname of such a kernel for the `:prepend-kernel` argument.

Answer (score 0):

To create executables of Clozure CL on Mac OS X:

- for non-GUI applications, you need to install Clozure CL from the repository: [Installing Clozure CL](http://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#installing). You need to [download CCL](http://ccl.clozure.com/download.html) from there. This version comes with an executable Lisp (kernel + image), which hasn't the GUI loaded.
- for GUI applications you need to use the [Application Builder](http://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#the-application-builder). The corresponding function is `ccl::build-application`. GUI applications on Mac OS X need some infrastructure, which is created then. Note that CCL comes with a example application in `ccl/examples/cocoa/currency-converter/`. Personally I would also prefer to use CCL from the repository - it's usually a bit newer than the version in the Mac Application store.